# LuaLaTeX unrecognized option -max-print-line=120

Tags: luatex, texniccenter, compilation-error

I am using TeXnicCenter and I am trying to compile a file using as output profile "LuaLaTeX => PDF". However, the compilation stops almost immediately after a few lines (4 in total), the first of which is

> lualatex: unrecognized option "-max-print-line=120"

and then it produces no file. Not even a log file.

Here's a mini-working example:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion?

Is it possible to remove and reinstall formats on MiKTeX as we do with packages, to try to restore LuaLaTeX?

**EDIT:** I went to "build > Define output profiles > LuaLaTeX => PDF" and there was appearing `-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm` into the Command lines argument to pass to the compiler. I removed `-max-print-line=120`, it seems that TeXnicCenter installed a lot of packages and now it is working. However, my question now is: why?

Every output profile has the `-max-print-line=120` option and none of the is complaining. Could somebody try to explain me what's going on?

Comment: Check at first the profile setting in texniccenter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the suggestion, but could you tell me more please? What do you mean by "check the profile setting"?

Comment: You are the one using texniccenter, an editor that has not been updated since 2014. How was lualatex even added to texniccenter in the first place? Not many editors listed lualatex out of the box back in 2014.(If I remember correctly, the profile is found in one of the menus)

Comment: @daleif Oh. I am using texniccenter since 2010 and I always found myself confortable with it. I tried TeXworks once, but it drove me crazy and after a week I moved back to texcniccenter. Which editor would you suggest?

Comment: I would not recommend it to new users given that (1) it is not being updated and (2) does need external setup for previewers. My own setup is also like that, but I'm not  a new user and have been using this for like 20 years. For new users I'd probably recommend texmaker or texstudio (they have the same origin). The latter has the most features. I like how they help while typing, tc's help while typing always annoyed me